# C: Most efficient way to set all bits in a range within a variable

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Let's take `int` as an example:

```
int SetBitWithinRange(const unsigned from, const unsigned to)
{
    //To be implemented 
}
```

`SetBitWithinRange` is supposed to return an `int`in which all and only the bits starting at bit `from` to bit `to` are set, when from is `smaller` than `to` and both are in the range of `0` to `32`.

e.g.:
`int i = SetBitWithinRange(2,4)` will result in `i` having the value of 0b00...01100

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c) and adapt it in a loop

Comment: Why don't you try implementing it and see what you can come up with.

Comment: This seems like it could be homework.. anyway, here's an idea. Set `n` bits, then shift them by `from`.

Comment: `int value = 0; int bit = (1 << from); value |= bit;` -- apply that to the remaining bits.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, Surely I can do it in a loop. I was wondering though if there is a faster way of doing that.

Comment: @Subway there is, in fact there are several ways, and they differ in what happens in edge cases (for example, if the range is empty, if the range is all bits, or if `to` includes the top bit)

Comment: Maybe you should have put the requirement about NOT using a loop in the question.

Comment: In your example, it looks like only bits 2 and 3 are set (assume counting from 0, starting from the right).  Does that mean Param#1 is *inclusive*, but Param#2 is *exclusive*?  That seems confusing.  For `SetBit(2,4)`, I would expect the output to be `0b00011100` (bits 2 through 4 set... again assuming 0-based, from right).

Comment: Why the range 0 to 32?  It seems artificial.  I'd expect range 0 to 31 (or better `0 to sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BIT-1`) or 0 to `UINT_MAX`?

Comment: @chux has an excellent point.  Range 0-32 actually represents **33** places.   You should choose (and state clearly) if this is 0-based (0-31 range), or 1-based (1-32 range).

Comment: "when `from` is smaller than `to` and both are in the range of 0 to 32." is contradictory. Both `to` and `from` can't be in the same range _and_ `from` is smaller than `to`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some ways. First, some variants of "set `n` bits, then shift by `from`". I'll answer in C# though, I'm more familiar with it than I am with C. Should be easy to convert.

```
uint nbits = 0xFFFFFFFFu >> -(to - from);
return nbits << from;
```

Downside: can't handle an empty range, ie the case where `to <= from`.

```
uint nbits = ~(0xFFFFFFFFu << (to - from));
return nbits << from;
```

Upside: can handle the case where `to = from` in which case it will set no bits.
Downside: can't handle the full range, ie setting all bits.

It should be obvious how these work.

Alternatively, you can use the "subtract two powers of two" trick,

```
(1u << to) - (1u << from)
```

Downside: `to` can not be 32, so you can never set the top bit.

Works like this:

```
01000000
  ^^^^^^ "to" zeroes
     100
      ^^ "from zeroes"
-------- -
00111100
```

To the right of the 1 in the "from" part, it's just zeroes being subtracted from zeroes. Then at the 1 in the "from" part, you will either subtract from a 1 (if `to == from`) and get 0 as a result, or you'll subtract a 1 from a 0 and borrow all the way to the 1 in the `to` part, which will be reset.

All true bitwise methods that have been proposed at the time of writing have one of those downsides, which raises the question: can it be done without downsides?

The answer is, unfortunately, disappointing. It can be done without downsides, but only by

1. cheating (ie using non-bitwise elements), or
2. more operations than would be nice, or
3. non-standard operations

To give an example of 1, you can just pick any of the previous methods and add a special case (with an `if` or ternary operator) to work around their downside.

To give an example of 2: (not tested)

```
uint uppermask = (((uint)to >> 5) ^ 1) << to;
return uppermask - (1u << from);
```

The `uppermask` either takes a 1 and shifts it left by `to` (as usual), or it takes a 0 and shifts it left (by an amount that doesn't matter, since it's 0 that's being shifted), if `to == 32`. But it's kind of weird and uses more operations.

To give an example of 3, shifts that give zero when you shift by the operand size or more would solve this very easily. Unfortunately, that kind of shift isn't too common.

Answer (score 5):

A common way to do this somewhat efficiently would be this:

```
uint32_t set_bits_32 (uint32_t data, uint8_t offset, uint8_t n)
{
  uint32_t mask = 0xFFFFFFFF >> (32-n);

  return data | (mask << offset);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with something like that:

```
int answer = 0;
unsigned i = from;
for (; i <= to; ++i)
  answer |= (1 << i);

return answer;
```

Easy to implement & readable.

I think that the fastest way would be to pre-calculate all possible values (from (0, 0) to (32, 32), if you know that you'll use this only for 32-bit integers). In fact there are about 1000 of them.

Then you'll end up with O(1) solution:

```
answer = precalcTable[from][to];
```

Answer (score 4):

OK, I'm taking up the gauntlet that @JohnZwinck has thrown towards me.

How about:
`return (to<32 ? (1<<to) : 0) - (1<<from);`

Of course this is without fully checking for validity of `from` and `to`.

Edited according to @JosephQuinsey comments.

Comment: Perhaps change `1` to `1U`, as `1 << 31` is Undefined Behavior on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: And your question said "range of `0` to `32`". But `1U << 32` is IIRC undefined behavior on a typical 32-bit machine.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey things aren't undefined on machines, they're undefined in the standard. On a typical machine it's defined, but often defined in such a way that it won't work (`1 << 32 == 1`, often).

Comment: Just because some code is compact doesn't necessarily mean it is efficient. You have one comparison, two shifts, one subtraction and a branch. If you look at the code I posted, it is very similar but with a bitwise OR instead of branching. Branching may or may not make the whole code less efficient, depending on CPU.

Comment: This seems like a cheat. You're asking for bit-manipulation, but you're using a branch.

Comment: @harold: For `unsigned x = 1U; printf("%u %u\n", 1U << 32, x << 32);` gcc with `-O0` gives the _inconsistent_ results `0 1` (and this is what I would expect it to do). (It also warns "left shift count >= width of type", twice.)

Comment: @JosephQuinsey of course it does, but it's GCC doing that, not the machine. On any sane machine (and even x86, often accused of not being sane), the machine instructions for shifts are perfectly well-defined for any input.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey I'm really not arguing that it's defined in C. Almost nothing is. But you said "undefined behaviour on a typical 32-bit *machine*", which is completely untrue.

Comment: Regarding `<< 32`, the C11 standard 6.5.7[3] states: _"If the value of the right operand is ... equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined."_ This is what I meant by my sloppy phrase _typical 32-bit machine_. Of course on many machines, an int can have various widths, depending on the compiler settings.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey oh right, so you mean in C, and just put the "32-bit machine" in there to mean "unsigned ints are 32 bits"

Answer (score 1):

maybe: `(( 1 << to ) - (1 << from)) | (1 << to)`

This will also set the to and from bits as requested

Comment: Sorry, my question was misleading, I meant to have `to` unset. Edited the question.

Comment: @Subway you mean you want to have 0's instead of 1s?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer. (*updated*)

```
unsigned int SetBits(int from, int to)
{    
    return (UINT_MAX >> (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)-to)) & (UINT_MAX << (from-1));
}

SetBits(9,16); ==> 0b 1111 1111 0000 0000

SetBits(1,1); ==> 0b 0000 0001  // Just Bit #1
SetBits(5,5); ==> 0b 0001 0000  // Just Bit #5
SetBits(1,4); ==> 0b 0000 1111  // Bits #1, #2, #3, and #4 (low 4 bits) 
SetBits(1,32); ==> 0b 1111 1111 1111 1111  // All Bits
```

However, `SetBits(0,0);` does NOT work for turning all bits off.

My assumptions:

- Bits are 1-based, starting from the right.
- Bytes are 8-bits.
- Ints can be any size (16, 32 or 64 bit). sizeof(int) is used.
- No checking is done on `from` or `to`; caller must pass proper values.

Comment: +1 for the "Ints can be any size".  BTW: If code uses `CHAR_BIT` rather than 8, you can drop assumption "Bytes are 8-bits."

Comment: Note: do you want `UINT_MAX` rather than `INT_MAX`?

Comment: Might want to consider splitting that line into several, for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in this way as well, pow can be implemented using shift operations.

```
{
    unsigned int i =0;
    i = pow(2, (to-from))-1;
    i = i <<from;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: The pow function as defined by the C standard is using floating point, so it is utterly ineffective. I take it you are suggesting to make your own, integer-based pow() function? Still, I don't see how that would improve efficiency.